# Как вывести значение из двух объединенных таблиц?

Tags: laravel

Есть две таблицы, user и post. мне надо вывести user с записями из post которые принадлежат ему.

**User table**
id: 1
name: Alex

id: 2
name: Ilya

**Post table**
id: 1
title: Good News
user_id: 1

id: 2
title: Very good news
user_id: 2

id: 3
title: Not bad good news
user_id: 2

**Нужен такой езультат:**
Alex
Good News

Ilya
Very good news
Not bad good news

**Что у меня получчается на данный момент:**
Почему-то вместо заголовка выходит объект
Alex
[{"id":1,"title":"Good News.","user_id":1,"}]

Ilya
[{"id":2,"title":"Very good news.","user_id":2,"}]
[{"id":3,"title":"Not bad good news.","user_id":2,"}]

**Post model:**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**User model:**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

**Controller**

```
$users = User::with('posts')->get();
    $posts = Post::with('user')->get();
    return view('index', compact('users', 'posts'));
```

**View:**

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
<h3>{{ $user->name}}</h3>
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <p>{{ $post->title }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже эти данные относятся к модели **User**. И я очень сомневаюсь, что их вам отдает `$post->title`.

> Alex
>
> [{"id":1,"title":"Good News.","user_id":1,"}]
>
> Ilya
>
> [{"id":2,"title":"Very good news.","user_id":2,"}]
>
> [{"id":3,"title":"Not bad good news.","user_id":2,"}]

Если вы хотите получить пользователя со связанными с ним постами достаточно одного запроса.

**Controller**

```
$users = User::with('posts')->get();
return view('index', compact('users'));
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
<h3>{{ $user->name}}</h3>
    @foreach ($user->posts as $post)
        <p>{{ $post->title }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Спасибо работает!